# What is the conventional way to write external SQL files in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm making a Django app that connects to a PostreSQL database other than the database used by the Django app itself. currently, I'm writing SQL code inside constant strings in python files, most queries contain multiple variables which are retrieved from the python script at runtime like:

```
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect("connection information"))
cursor = connection.cursor()
customer_id = 5
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id = {0}'.format(customer_id))
```

Howere, the SQL code will be more sophisticated than this and I have many different queries that need to be saved and reused and putting just inside python files is a very bad and unorganized way so I would prefer to save them in external files but also I wanna make sure I'm still following Django's conventions.

So where should I be saving my custom .sql fils? is there any special utility for this in Django?

Comment: you can set up multiple database connections in Django, and just use the ORM.

Comment: That would be a nice approach too but I think I would still be writing custom SQL because the SQL code I write is for dynamically creating tables and event handling functions... not just basic select and insert queries

The example above is just for a simple demonstration